# How to run Docker deamon on shared Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-registry

I have a problem starting Docker deamon. The root cause of this are missing modules in linux kernel. I don't have possibility to change/update the kernel.

Is there a workaround that would help me start Docker?

If that helps: the goal I want to achieve is to set up a repository of the Docker images. I won't run any containers on that computer.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-042stab12.5 x86_64

Comment: Could you please tell me why you down voted so I can improve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

(1) Run a Virtual Machine (hopefully with hardware acceleration), install the docker daemon/registry/whatever you need inside the VM and proxy network connections from the host to the VM.

(2) If you simply want to run a registry, find one that does not require the docker daemon to be installed to run.

Comment: I can't run virtual machines on this computer. I didn't know that there are docker registers that don't require running docker daemon to function properly I will try to find something.

Comment: @Furiia, you can actually setup and install a docker registry without needing docker. The only reason the docker-registry is distributed as a docker container is because it makes packaging and deployment easier. There's no docker requirement in the registry itself if you look at https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/Dockerfile